# Display 1st precision value after decimal (In oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the table with following values

```
Column_A (Type is Varchar)
  0.181
   165
  0.13
  0.034
  Count
```

Required Out Put

```
18.1%
165
13.0%
3.4%
Count
```

So only for decimal values it should be converted in percentages.

I tried through following syntax which is working fine for all results and only issue here is for value 0.13 producing to 13%  but not 13.0%

```
SELECT 
CASE  WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%.%' THEN CAST(CAST(COLUMN_A AS DECIMAL(10,3))*100 AS VARCHAR2(8))||'%'  ELSE COLUMN_F END AS COLUMN_F
FROM   Table_a;
```

Does anyone have quick suggestions to change in the query?

Comment: What does "decimal values" mean to you?  Is that any numeric value less than 1?  Or an numeric value that is not an integer?  Or something else?

Comment: @Justin Yes its any numeric value which is not Integer. The Original Column type is Varchar and it has Int, Decimal and String Values. I should only convert the decimal type values as percentages.

Comment: what a strange requirement. Too bad if the percentage was an integer, i.e. 0% or 100%, it cannot be correctly interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN COLUMN_A LIKE '%.%' THEN
      TO_CHAR(CAST(COLUMN_A AS DECIMAL(10,3))*100, '999.0') || '%'
    ELSE COLUMN_A
   END AS COLUMN_F
FROM   Table_a;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14378/2)

Share and enjoy.